# Android JSON user registration

Tags: android, api, registration

I'm in the process of building an Android application that interacts via a JSON API with my website.  I've basically got everything together except for user registration on the app.  I have an idea on how I want to implement it, but I want to see if there might be an easier way.

My approach is:

1. When the `RegisterActivity` is started, display a loading indicator, and make an asynchronous JSON request (via [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)) to the server get all the fields needed for registration.
2. When the listener receives a response, populate the spinners, checkboxes, etc. with the possible registration field values.
3. Allow the user to complete the form and submit via JSON.

You're probably thinking, "Why don't you just store the possible registration spinner/checkbox values in the app itself?"  The possible values for each field will be changing over time as I continue to test/push the product, and I don't want to break a build simply because I added/removed some possible options on the server.  This is why I'm dynamically building the form based upon a JSON request.

Given that, I'm wondering:

- Am I thinking about this the wrong way?
- If this is a good approach, is there a JAR or sample implementation someone has out there that already accomplishes this?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just use a WebView and have your registration page written in HTML and hosted on your server. That simplifies things dramatically.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: I thought about that, but one of the things I want to happen upon registration is that I log the user into the app.  Is there a way to capture response data for a specific request from a WebView into an Android app?

Comment: You can use shouldOverrideUrlLoading: "Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView. If WebViewClient is not provided, by default WebView will ask Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the url. If WebViewClient is provided, return true means the host application handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles the url" http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)

Comment: You can also use Javascript events that are picked up by Android.

Comment: Both techniques are explained in detail on this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html